# Adding a new mod_rewrite rule, containing a generated ID, to an existing configuration

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Yet another one I suppose...

How can I rewrite

`http://domain.com/images/download/30`

where `30` is a generated ID to

`http://domain.com/pages/files/download.php?id=30`

My current attempt looks like this:

`RewriteRule .+images/download/(\d+)    /pages/files/download.php?id=$1`

Where am I going wrong here?

The rest of my .htaccess is:

```
# turn rewriting on
RewriteEngine on

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&var1=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before other rules add

```
RewriteRule ^images/download/(\d+)$ /pages/files/download.php?id=$1 [L]
```

and in `/pages/` folder yo should switch off Rewrite Engine to avoid new rewrites on onther rules

Comment: Thank you very much! I was so close.